# session updated_at should be stopped in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on sso . a request comes from other application and after getting that request i am calling 1 method in my omniauth callback controller and response with a json object . but after complition of response it updates the updated_at of respective session. i want to stop updating updated_at for respective session.

Answer (score 0):

omniauth will do some session tasks for you, so your session gets update after omniauth callback. As your session is updated, your `updated_at` value in session is updated by rails automatically( and reasonably).

I don't think you can achieve your goal without customizing rails source code, which is obviously not a good idea.

If you don't want to use the value in `updated_at`, just ignore it or set it as nil

```
session[:updated_at] = nil
```

if you want to keep the value before omniauth callback:

```
original_updated_time = session[:updated_at]
YOUR CALLBACK LOGIC
session[:updated_at] = original_updated_time
```